# Vector of string push back problem, can you guys help me?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm creating a little program in order to test the vector class.
I'm using a string vector then i read a text file and i'm tring to write each word in the vector (1 word for each space).
When I try to use the push_back in order to put a string into the vector appear an error that says "There isn't a function to convert a string to a char".

If i made some english error sorry.
Thanks for the help.

I read some guide that explain how work the push_back but in all of this tutorial the use this declaration.

```
vector<string> v_of_string;<br/>
//allocate some memeory<br/>
v_of_string[1].pushback(string to punt in the vector);<br/>
```

My Code

```
int main() {
    vector<string> str; 
    //allocate some memory 
    ifstream iFile("test.txt"); 
    int i = 0;
    if (iFile.is_open()) {       
        while (!iFile.eof()) {
            string temp;
            iFile >> temp;
            str[i].push_back(temp);
            cout << str[i];
            i++;
        }

        iFile.close();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. YOu can do so by selecting the code and pressing the {} button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Answer (score 4):

So

```
str[i].push_back(temp);
```

is an error, you meant

```
str.push_back(temp);
```

You `push_back` to the vector as a whole, not to one particular element of the vector, so there is no need for `[i]`. I expect if you go back to your guide then it will say the same.

You could also replace `cout << str[i];` with `cout << str.back();` to always output the last element of the vector. So actually you don't need the variable `i` at all.

Also

```
while (!iFile.eof()) {
    string temp;
    iFile >> temp;
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
string temp;
while (iFile >> temp) {
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) for an explanation. I'd be interested if you got this code from your guide as well. Using `eof` in a while loop in C++ must be single commonest error we see on stack overflow.

Incidentally `str` is a poor choice of name for a vector variable IMHO.